# sharing Internet connection with 2 nic

Tags: networking, router, bridge, ics, bridge-router

OK I may not have done all the research but I see by virtualrouting.codeplex.com that it is possible...
I am running into an issue.
I have currently broadband access connecting to the wan port of my wireless / wired router. However it (internet access) intermittently goes down.

I want to install a second NIC in the PC closest to the router so that
I can use the output of the second NIC in a windows (xp,7,8) pc to be the input of my wan port of an existing LAN ...

That is when my broadband goes out I want to connect my PC to my phone (USB)... tether it for an internet connection and connect that pc to the wan port of my wireless / wired home router which will supply private ip address to the rest of my LAN

To put it another way I want to disconnect the broadband which is not working and connect my second nic of my PC to supply internet access to my LAN and be able to switch back again when I get the broadband access back

Currently I am using the private ip range of address 192.168.xxx.xxx but I have static ips in that range port forwarding  etc so this way I would not have to change anything on my LAN just lose the use of 1 PC for the duration of the outage.

I am thinking that I could by software disable the NIC that is connected to the existing LAN and plug the phone in get an ip from the cell provider and then just plug in the second NIC to the router and shazaam!

Comments ?? suggestions???